# Swift - How to forbid an initializer?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller

Consider the following controller class with a delegate:

```
@objc protocol FooControllerDelegate {
}

@objc class FooController: UIViewController {
    var delegate: FooControllerDelegate

    init(delegate: FooControllerDelegate) {
        self.delegate = delegate
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    // TODO: How do we forbid this init?
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        // TODO: Fails to compile.
        super.init(coder: aDecoder) 
    }
}
```

Is there any way to forbid the usage of the `-initWithCoder:` equivalent, without making the delegate implicitly unwrapped, and placing an `assert(false)` inside the method?

Ideally, it won't be necessary to write the `init(coder:)` with each subclass at all, and have it implicitly forbidden.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- If the goal to forbid usage of **all designated initializers** besides yours then there's no language feature at this moment. This applies to all kinds of methods.

> Overriding method must be accessible as it's enclosing type

- If the goal is to avoid empty override of `init(coder:)` each time you adding custom initialiser then think about `convenience` keyword. Swift's safety paradigm assumes that class either adds 'additional' init or has to modify behaviour of all required initialisers.

["Automatic Initializer Inheritance"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID222)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `@available` [attribute](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Attributes.html) like mentioned [here](https://www.jessesquires.com/blog/2020/05/20/marking-unused-required-initializers-as-unavailable/)?

> Luckily, you can use Swift’s @available attribute to prevent this, which also has the benefit of more clearly communicating that you should not use this initializer.

The solution seems to work pretty well:

```swift
@available(*, unavailable)
public required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        
}
```